# Spring boot with redis caching, Cannot get Jedis connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis-cache

I have an spring boot application with using hibernate with MySQL as DB.

I'm going to use `Redis` for caching, This is my Spring config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableCaching
public class MyApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AbcApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

And my properties file in class path:

```
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.redis.host=127.0.0.1
spring.redis.port=6379
```

User model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

And repository interface:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

I've put Caching annotation on a controller endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
@Cacheable(value = "user", key = "#id")
public ResponseEntity getUserDetail(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    User user = userService.getById(id);

    return ResponseEntity.ok("user id: " + user.getId());
}
```

But when i'm invoking this endpoint, this exception thrown:

```
Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have a Redis running on localhost address and 6379 port?

Comment: @Dherik How can i make sure?